# How to enable https support for curl in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, ssl, curl, https

I have a "curl" program installed on Ubuntu 14.04 Server. Unfortunately, it does not support https.

I have googled this problem and found a suggestion to replace "curl" package with "curl-ssl", but "apt-get" can not find it.

I definitely do not want to compile it by myself.
Help me, please.
Here is my curl -V output:

```
curl 7.37.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.37.1 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap pop3 rtsp scp sftp smtp telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile
```

**UPD**
I have found file /usr/local/bin/curl, which is always 7.37, it does not depend of package installed via apt-get

**UPD** 
whereis curl:

```
 curl: /usr/bin/curl /usr/local/bin/curl /usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz
```

Comment: curl on Ubuntu 14.04 should support https without additional packages, because it depends on libcurl3 which itself depends on libssl1.0.0 which provides the SSL support needed for https. What makes you think that it doesn't support https?

Comment: Could you please add to your question the output of `curl --version`?

Comment: Where did you get this version from? According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/curl ubuntu 14.04 ships with  7.35 (not 7.37.1) and this one should be compiled with SSL support.

Comment: I have done "apt-get install curl", but after your remark I've run cat for "/etc/apt/sources.list" and now I see some additional repos. I will check it: may be they are reason.

Comment: What does `whereis curl` say?

Comment: You have a `curl` present in `/usr/bin/curl`. I'd wager that one has HTTPS support, but `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin/` in the PATH, which is why you're having problems. Either use the full path (`/usr/bin/curl`), or add an alias which uses the full path.

Comment: Unfortunately, both versions of curl use the same version of libcurl3, which is located under a path /usr/local/lib/ and doesn't  have https support.  Fortunately, I have found the workaround for this problem.
Anyway, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Be careful**, it is dangerous and may not be what you need

```
rm /usr/local/lib/libcurl*
```

It makes Ubuntu use package instead of compiled version of curl

Comment: yeah that broke curl for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are being misled by the error message

`curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to example.com:443`

It means that curl had trouble finding a matching SSL protocol version.

Try adding `-3` or even `--insecure` to help curl find a usable SSL version.